# How to perform real time face detection in Windows 10 camera application?

Tags: c++, windows-10, face-detection, openvino

I have been trying a long time to integrate Open Vino Face dectection ADAS model into the MFT pipeline so as to make my Windows 10 camera application detect faces at real time. But nothing worked out.

I am using visual studio 2019 and trying to code in C++ to develop a driver for the camera that does the face detection.

Is there any other way to make the windows 10 camera application to detect faces and draw a bounding box around the detected faces automatically while capturing?

Any help or suggestions are welcome

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the [Object Detection Demo](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/omz_demos_object_detection_demo_python.html) application in the OpenVINO toolkit to run the [face-detection-adas-0001](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/omz_models_model_face_detection_adas_0001.html) model. You need to download the model and convert it to OpenVINO Intermediate Representation format. Then, run the demo by using the following command:

*python object_detection_demo.py -i 0 -m "<INSTALL_DIR>\openvino_2021.4.582\deployment_tools\tools\model_downloader\intel\face-detection-adas-0001\FP16\face-detection-adas-0001.xml" -at ssd*

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Object Detection C++ Demo](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/omz_demos_object_detection_demo_cpp.html) in the OpenVINO toolkit to run the [face-detection-adas-0001](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/omz_models_model_face_detection_adas_0001.html) model. The face-detection-adas-0001 model is from [Intel's Pre-Trained Models](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/omz_models_group_intel.html), so you just need to download the model and run it with the demo. While for [Public Pre-Trained Models](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/omz_models_group_public.html), you need to download and convert them to Intermediate Representation format.